# Print contents of PHP file in email message / body

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I want to write a PHP page to run on a cron job to email out the contents of a PHP page.

When trying this, I get the scripts included in the body of the email, not just the echoed out elements.

Here is the script I'm using below currently to try and include kpi.php in the email.

**Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?**

*alternatively I'd be happy to grab a screenshot of the page.*

Thanks

```html
<?php
$to = "email@domai.com";
$subject = "Daily Update";


$message = include('kpi.php');

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <no-reply@email.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php explains how "returning values" from included files works. If your include file is not written accordingly (and can't be, because it needs to work without "returning" in other contexts) - then you will have to use output buffering instead.

Comment: thanks bizzarely this has actually solved my query I think. I'll just include it before hand and echo the variables I need into the body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

Just include it beforehand and echo the variables needed into the body of the email